# Is there any way to compile Java code into a DLL?

Tags: java, dll

See question above.

Comment: What exactly is your purpose for doing this?  Knowing your motivation might get you a better answer.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, use IKVM.

http://www.ikvm.net/

And it's incredibly easy to use:

```
ikvmc myjar.jar
```

outputs myjar.dll

Comment: do I need the .NET plataform to use this dll ? or its native to win32, and I can use it with C++ ? Sry I dont know much about .NET

Answer (score 2):

There is also [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) which will compile classes into native format.

Comment: Just FYI this answer is now well out of date see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040404/3195477

Answer (score -6):

It is better to create a c++ loader which

1)Hides the console

2)runs your application

Comment: This is not an answer. Please explain why `is it better to create a c++ loader` and *how* to do it.