# How to open the .dll files of the Java.

Tags: java, dll, bin

I want to see the source code of the .dll file of Java which is stored in the Java installation folder that is stored in the folder bin under JRE folder which is stored in Java installation folder. I used dotpeek by JetBrains but it shows no supported. 
plz tell me how can I open the source code of that .dll files.

Comment: Java source files are compiled to .class files. As far as I know, there is no standard way to compile java code to a DLL.

Comment: You would need to have a decompiler for the specific language the dll was written in, but depending on WHAT dll it is this action might even be illegal. I don't think this question belongs here.

Comment: I think answers to this question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/where-to-find-java-jdk-source-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java source files are compiled to .class files. As far as I know, there is no standard way to compile java code to a DLL.

But, check this post [Decompile JAVA DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171295/decompile-java-dll)

Check this page, is a online jar and class java decompiler https://jdec.herokuapp.com

Although you can try this

Read the file:

```
JarInputStream input = new JarInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myjar.dll"));
```

Write a new file for each entry:

```
JarEntry entry;
while ((entry = input.getNextJarEntry()) != null)
{
    // Write file
}
```

For dissasembly DLL, chek this https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/ZWzEu8hz

[image]

[image]

Comment: But there are many .dll files in the JRE folder is there no way to decompile that .dll files

Comment: @212121 If you check the post that you put, you will see that these are not written in Java, but in another language, since Java does not create dll. Test with a decompiler of C, C ++, C #, etc
It all depends on the language in which this writing, if you could leave the link to download one of those dll to see if it can be decompiled, maybe it can help you

Comment: @212121 Look this dll disassembler https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/ZWzEu8hz