# Convert Java class to DLL

Tags: c#, java, .net, dll

I need to use Java code in .NET (C#) and am looking for a way to convert a Java class to a DLL file (which I can then reference in my .NET app). Is this a valid scenario? If yes, How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/262603/93732

Comment: You could also look at the Java Native Interface (JNI) to allow your .NET code to call your Java code and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/uses.html) to use Java classes and libraries from .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Basically that is not a good idea. Since java emphasizes on platform independence, but dll is platform dependent. So, think about pack into a jar file, execute and consume it somehow

May be this link will be useful for you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13549/Using-Java-Classes-in-your-NET-Application

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use IKVM.NET.